# Problem with testing a name service smart contract written in Solang

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, solang

I'm trying to run a benchmark for a Solana node using this name service I wrote in Solang within an Anchor project.

This is the Solang smart contract.

```
import 'solana';

contract eclipse_ns {
    uint64 constant ERROR_INVALID_NAME = 2;    
    uint64 constant ERROR_INVALID_LENGTH = 5;
    uint64 constant SMALLEST_GAS_UNIT = 10**9;
    address payable public owner;
    string public tld;
    mapping(string => address) public domains;
    string[] private domainKeys;
    mapping(string => string) public records;

    @space(10240)
    @payer(payer) 
    constructor(string memory _tld, address initial_owner) {
        owner = payable(initial_owner);
        tld = _tld;
    }
        function valid(string calldata name) public pure returns(bool) {
        uint len = bytes(name).length;
        // Length constraints
        if (len < 3 || len > 20) {
            return false;
        }
        // Check if the name ends with ".ecl"
        return endsWith(name, ".ecl");
    }

    // Suffix test
    function endsWith(string memory str, string memory suffix) internal pure returns (bool) {
        bytes memory strBytes = bytes(str);
        bytes memory suffixBytes = bytes(suffix);
        if (strBytes.length < suffixBytes.length) {
            return false;
        }
        uint suffixStartIndex = strBytes.length - suffixBytes.length;
        for (uint i = 0; i < suffixBytes.length; i++) {
            if (strBytes[i + suffixStartIndex] != suffixBytes[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the test that mints 100 domains at once and calculates the time taken to do so.

```
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { EclipseNs } from "../target/types/eclipse_ns";

describe("eclipse_ns", () => {
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const program = anchor.workspace.eclipse_ns as Program<EclipseNs>;

  it("Mints 100 domains with .ecl", async () => {
    const promises = [];
    const nameRecordOwner = Keypair.generate(); 

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const initialOwner = Keypair.generate().publicKey;
      const domainName = `test${i}.ecl`;

      const promise = initializeDomain(nameRecordOwner, initialOwner)
        .then(() => registerDomain(domainName, nameRecordOwner, initialOwner))
        .then((tx) => {
          console.log(
            `${domainName} owned by ${initialOwner} with name record ${nameRecordOwner.publicKey}. Transaction: ${tx}`
          );
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(`Error registering domain ${domainName}:`, err);
        });

      promises.push(promise);
    }

    await Promise.all(promises).catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error with batch processing:", err);
    });
  });

  function initializeDomain(nameRecordOwner, initialOwner) {
    return program.methods
      .new("ecl", initialOwner)
      .accounts({
        dataAccount: nameRecordOwner.publicKey,
        payer: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .signers([nameRecordOwner])
      .rpc()
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error initializing domain:", err);
        throw err; 
      });
  }

  function registerDomain(domainName, nameRecordOwner, initialOwner) {
    return program.methods
      .register(domainName, new anchor.BN(50 * 10 ** 9), initialOwner)
      .accounts({
        dataAccount: nameRecordOwner.publicKey,
        ownerAccount: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
      })
      .signers([program.provider.wallet.payer])
      .rpc()
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error registering domain:", err);
        throw err;
      });
  }
});
```

I keep running into this error

```
Error initializing domain: SendTransactionError: Raw transaction 2b9oiRBwSBvxr57BwEFiCj59ZPE2m56BrM6YKbZdpwNCwGyWYDf4JcsPmLZUXsstrFb2uZyBvJ2sPp1mEPcij9bx failed ({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,{"Custom":2}]}})
    at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/Users/pratham/Documents/GitHub/eclipse-benchmarking/svm/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:181:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (/Users/pratham/Documents/GitHub/eclipse-benchmarking/svm/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
    at async Promise.all (index 5) {
  logs: [
    'Program 3FeFUn3mng4psjHTwWwQUZPvisxVVxZ3UVPAtVBfKG6b invoke [1]',
    'Program 3FeFUn3mng4psjHTwWwQUZPvisxVVxZ3UVPAtVBfKG6b consumed 274 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program 3FeFUn3mng4psjHTwWwQUZPvisxVVxZ3UVPAtVBfKG6b failed: custom program error: 0x2'
  ],
  programErrorStack: ProgramErrorStack {
    stack: [
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(3FeFUn3mng4psjHTwWwQUZPvisxVVxZ3UVPAtVBfKG6b)]]
    ]
  }
}
```

This is on AVM V0.29.0, how should I go about resolving this problem?

I'm not sure if Custom: 2 error is reffering to `ERROR_INVALID_NAME = 2` in the solang contract or something else.